# Return to start of the Java code(main menu of calculator)

Tags: java, return, calculator

I am new and somewhat a noob to Java, and I'm trying to make a calculator, didn't test everything to see if it works, but I'm having a problem. I can't seem to figure out how do I get back to the main menu after performing one calculation. I have added that question in the end to make it prompt the user either to exit or continue back to the main menu. I just don't know what to put in the if(whatnow == Y){ wtf am i supposed to do to get back to the main menu?? }. Sorry if it was a bit long or something, but they're really all the same so just skip the calculation thingy. Any help appreciated. I am really new to java and i probably have to write this code all over again.

```
package practice;

import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int choice;
    int firstnumber;
    int secondnumber;
    int result;
    char whatnow;

    System.out.println("Welcome to StemCalc Z Edition(Integers only)!");
    System.out.println("Made with love and basic Java");
    System.out.println("Which math operation would you like to perform?");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("WARNING: Enter the integer x, press ENTER, then enter y");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("[1]-Addition (+)");
    System.out.println("[2]-Subtraction (-)");
    System.out.println("[3]-Multiplication (x)");
    System.out.println("[4]-Division (/)");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Enter your choice[1-4 or 99]:"); choice = scan.nextInt();

    while ((choice < 1 || choice > 4) && choice != 99) {
        System.out.println("Please enter 1, 2, 3, 4, or 99: ");
        choice = scan.nextInt();
    }

    if (choice == 1){
        System.out.println("Enter two integer to add(x + y)");

        firstnumber = scan.nextInt();
        secondnumber = scan.nextInt();
        result = firstnumber + secondnumber;

        System.out.println(firstnumber + " + " + secondnumber + " = " + result);
    }

    else if (choice == 2) {
        System.out.println("Enter two integers to subtract(x - y)");

        firstnumber = scan.nextInt();
        secondnumber = scan.nextInt();
        result = firstnumber - secondnumber;

        System.out.println(firstnumber + " - " + secondnumber + " = " + result);
    }

    else if (choice == 3) {
        System.out.println("Enter two integers to multiply(x * y)");

        firstnumber = scan.nextInt();
        secondnumber = scan.nextInt();
        result = firstnumber * secondnumber;

        System.out.println(firstnumber + " * " + secondnumber + " = " + result);
    }

    else if (choice == 4) {
        System.out.println("Enter to integers to divide(x / y)");

        firstnumber = scan.nextInt();
        secondnumber = scan.nextInt();

        while (secondnumber == 0) {
            System.out.println("ERROR-CANNOT DIVIDE TO ZERO! Type another integer:");
            secondnumber = scan.nextInt();
        }

        result = firstnumber / secondnumber;

        System.out.println(firstnumber + " / " + secondnumber + " = " + result);
        }

    else if (choice == 99) {
        System.exit(0);

    }

    while (choice !=99) {
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue calculating? [Y/N]:"); whatnow = scan.next().charAt(0);

        if (whatnow == 'Y' || whatnow == 'y') {

        }

        if (whatnow == 'N' || whatnow == 'n') {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

}

P.S: I edited the end to look something like this with a while(true) at the beginning:

```
`while (choice !=99) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue calculating? [Y/N]:"); whatnow = scan.next().charAt(0);

            while(whatnow != 'Y' || whatnow != 'y' || whatnow !='N' || whatnow !='n') {
     System.out.println("Enter [Y/N] only:"); whatnow = scan.next().charAt(0);
            }

            if (whatnow == 'N' || whatnow == 'n') {
                System.exit(0);`
```

Comment: Move all your code into another method, and call that method when you need to return to start.

Comment: i'm a noob, the only method i know is public static void main(String args[]). Hell, i don't even know if THAT is a method or not :P

Comment: Yes, that is a method. And you should make another one like it, name it something decent and call it from inside `main` and whenever you need to go back. There should be enough info around so that you can keyword-search things from our conversation and understand what do you need to do.

Comment: Hi Ubuntu4EVA, please don't add answers and [solved] to the question. You may answer your question in the answer section and accept the answer (if you want to change the accepted answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to repeat everything you have written until the user insert `N`. So all you want to do is put everything inside a `while(true)` loop, whose last instruction will be:

```
if (whatnow == 'N' || whatnow = 'n') {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

This way, if the user inserts anything besides `N` or `n` the loop will bring him back to the main menu printing section, so maybe you would need to add a test on the value of `whatnow` in the same way you did for `choice`.

The result will be like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    ...

    while(true){
        System.out.println("Welcome to StemCalc Z Edition(Integers only)!");

        ...

        while (choice !=99) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue calculating? [Y/N]:"); whatnow = scan.next().charAt(0);

            //insert some loop to ensure that the value of whatnow will be either Y or N

            if (whatnow == 'N' || whatnow == 'n') {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is a sample code of what I anticipated with my last comment:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    char whatnow = 'Y';
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (whatnow != 'N' && whatnow != 'n') {
        int choice = printMenuAndAsk(scan);

        if (choice == 99)
            break;
        else performOperation(choice, scan);

        System.out.println("Do you want to continue calculating? [Y/N]:"); 
        whatnow = scan.next().charAt(0);

        while(whatnow != 'N' && whatnow != 'Y' && whatnow != 'n' && whatnow != 'y') { 
            System.out.println("Incorrect answer");
            whatnow = scan.next().charAt(0);
        }
    }   
    scan.close();   
}

public static int printMenuAndAsk(Scanner scan) {
    int choice;

    System.out.println("Welcome to StemCalc Z Edition(Integers only)!");
    ...
    System.out.println("Enter your choice[1-4 or 99]:"); 
    choice = scan.nextInt();

    while ((choice < 1 || choice > 4) && choice != 99) {
        System.out.println("Please enter 1, 2, 3, 4, or 99: ");
        choice = scan.nextInt();
    }

    return choice;
}

public static void performOperation(int operation, Scanner scan) {
    System.out.println("Enter first:");
    int firstnumber = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter second:");
    int secondnumber = scan.nextInt();

    if (choice == 1)
        System.out.println(firstnumber + " + " + secondnumber + " = " + (firstnumber+secondnumber));
    else if (choice == 2) 
        System.out.println(firstnumber + " - " + secondnumber + " = " + (firstnumber-secondnumber));
    else if (choice == 3) 
        System.out.println(firstnumber + " * " + secondnumber + " = " + (firstnumber*secondnumber));
    else if (choice == 4) {
        while (secondnumber == 0) {
            System.out.println("ERROR-CANNOT DIVIDE TO ZERO! Type another integer:");
            secondnumber = scan.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(firstnumber + " / " + secondnumber + " = " + (firstnumber/secondnumber));
    }
}
```

Comment: does whatnow != 'Y' work? for the loop to ensure the value is Y or N? if so,   do we need the if statement for Y?

Comment: can u please review my changes? just edited the orginal question

Comment: I'd say `while(whatnow != 'N' && whatnow != 'Y') { System.out.println("Incorrect answer");whatnow = scan.next().charAt(0);}`. After this is done `whatnow` will be either 'N' (in this case we exit) or 'Y' (in this case we don't have to do anything because we are at the end of the loop, and we will be brought to the beginning of the while) so we're done

Comment: The problem in what you've wrote is that you use `||` in the condition. If you insert an 'n', `whatnow != 'N'` is true and will cause the loop condition to be true. So basically you wrote an infinite cycle! Just replace `||` with `&&`

Comment: yeah, I didn't realize that. And changing that with adding if they input Y then break; and if they input N then system.exit(0), then so far it's flawless! thanks!

Comment: uh, hi. sorry for bringing up an old story, but I have been around long enough to mess with methods and strings, and I just want to ask: if I want my code to be more optimized and interchangeable, should i stick with while(true)? can I use nested while(true)s for submenus? or should I switch over to methods?

Comment: Well, gruping code into separate methods is always a good solution for code readability (assuming that such methods have meaningful names). Furthermore, since you are basically repeating the same operations in every if block, you should be able to write down a method that acquire two integers and, relying on a parameter, perform the desired operation and prints the result.

Comment: There is also a way to get rid of the while(true)s, using loops with more accurate conditions. Later I'll get to my computer and update my answer providinig an example code.

Comment: I like how the new thing works. Thanks a bunch! Quick questions: I've never seen any put a scanner as a parameter for a method, how different is it from just initializing a scanner for every method? or is it just to make the code shorter? And I'm thinking about adding a submenu method, an if-else would ask the user to select 1-4 or 99 to go back to top menu. So would I just put if(choice = 99) { printMenuandAsk() } or will i have to use a new code structure?

Comment: I think it's a good practice to open a stream when you need it and close it when you no longer need it. Repeatedly opening streams could slow down things. Imagine if you're working on a large file: the performance of your application would terribly degrade if you keep opening and closing the streams to such file. However, in your application, it makes no difference. Remember to ALWAYS close the streams you open! For submenus, that really depends on the behavior that you are looking for. In general, you can change the content of function `performOperation` in order to obtain what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to put a while loop at the end, try to put your entire code in a`while(true)` block. Using an if statement at the end, you can ask whether the user wants to continue our not. Exit the loop by using the`break` keyword.
Try to exit like this:

```
if(input == 'n'){break;}
```

What this does is that it exits the while loop. You can execute more instructions outside the `while` block.

Comment: I did not suggest using a function as you had stated that you were new to Java.

Comment: can you give like an example of that if statement at the end? I've seen others putting the while(true) thing then later make it false or something like that. but does that work like I intended it to? Asks the users whether if they want to exit or continue after calculating?

Comment: I added the while(true) but didn't know what to do with the while loop at the end, so i just left the Y blank and the N as break; like you said. Then when i run it on Eclipse's console, when I select Y it repeats the question(y not?), but when I select N, it actually returns to the menu for some stupid reason.... I'm a noob and I'm so confused

Comment: Are you trying to input 99 to exit the program in the first while loop in your code?

Comment: i entered 99 and it terminated normally

Comment: The if condition to exit the loop should be at the end. It would be wise to remove the condition to check for 99. Please do insert the `break` if the user does not want to continue. This allows the user to perform the operation and then considers if it had to exit the loop or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could change it as follows:

Your main method as such:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        calc();
    }
```

And then create a method named `calc()`:

```
public static void calc() {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //the rest of your code

 } else if (choice == 99) {
            System.exit(0);

        }

        calc(); //call the method again at the end of your code
                //remove your while loop

    }
```

Comment: Well, actually. Calling `calc()` from inside `calc()` will eventually cause a `StackOverflowError`. A loop is still a nice addition to this.

Comment: Yes, I guess it could eventually, I'm just giving some sort of a variation to the OP.